# git fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF - как отключить проверку?

Tags: git

Гит отказывается добавлять файлы, у которых перенос строк LF, просит изменить на CRLF. Хотел изменить вручную, но файлов очень много. Пытался отключить проверку формата с помощью git config core.autocrlf false, но не помогло. Подскажите, какие еще есть варианты решения проблемы? Заранее спасибо

Comment: [*файлов очень много*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unix2dos)

Comment: В [официальной документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Настройка-Git-Конфигурирование-Git) написано: "Если вы используете Windows, установите настройку в true, тогда концы строк из LF будут сконвертированы в CRLF при выгрузке кода", также там даются рекомендации относительно Linux и Mac, - в документации все довольно полно описано.

Comment: ну и как дополнительное чтение: `$ man git-config` на предмет `core.safecrlf`.